How to Move Active Conversations to Sidebar After Initiation in MERN Chat App?
I’m developing a real-time chat application using the MERN stack with Socket.IO for live updates. Right now, I have a popup that displays all users, which is triggered by a "START CHAT" button click. This part is working well.
However, I want to implement the following behavior for conversations:
Display Conversations in Sidebar: When a conversation is initiated or a message is exchanged, the involved users’ conversation should move from the popup to the sidebar. The sidebar should only display active conversations for the logged-in user.
Real-Time Updates: The sidebar should update in real-time to reflect new or ongoing conversations.

Current Setup
Users are already fetched in the popup based on hierarchy and can initiate a conversation from there.
Once a chat is initiated, I need the conversation (not just the user) to appear in the sidebar for both participants.
Conversations in the sidebar should be sorted by role and name, with real-time updates when a conversation is initiated or a message is sent.

Challenges
I need to adjust my backend endpoints and possibly my frontend logic to track and fetch only active conversations for the sidebar.
Conversations should no longer appear in the popup once they are in the sidebar.
Real-time updates are required so that both users see the active conversation appear in their sidebar.

import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Conversation from './Conversation';
import { useSocketContext } from '../../context/SocketContext';
import { useAuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext';
import useConversation from '../../zustand/useConversation';
import SearchInput from './SearchInput';

const Conversations = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [groupedUsers, setGroupedUsers] = useState({});
    const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
    const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const { socket } = useSocketContext();
    const { authUser } = useAuthContext();
    const { selectedConversation, setSelectedConversation } = useConversation();
    const popupRef = useRef(null);

    const reorderGroupsByMostRecent = (groupedUsers) => {
        const allUsers = Object.values(groupedUsers).flat();
        allUsers.sort((a, b) => {
            const aTimestamp = new Date(a.lastMessageTimestamp || 0).getTime();
            const bTimestamp = new Date(b.lastMessageTimestamp || 0).getTime();
            return bTimestamp - aTimestamp;
        });

        const newGroupedUsers = {};
        allUsers.forEach((user) => {
            if (!newGroupedUsers[user.roleName]) {
                newGroupedUsers[user.roleName] = [];
            }
            newGroupedUsers[user.roleName].push(user);
        });

        return newGroupedUsers;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUsers = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('/api/users');
                if (response.data && typeof response.data === 'object') {
                    setGroupedUsers(response.data);
                } else {
                    console.error("Unexpected API response format");
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching users", error);
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        fetchUsers();

        if (socket) {
            socket.on("updateSidebar", ({ senderId, receiverId, message }) => {
                const targetUserId = senderId === authUser.id ? receiverId : senderId;

                setGroupedUsers((prevGroupedUsers) => {
                    const updatedGroupedUsers = { ...prevGroupedUsers };
                    let updatedUser = null;

                    for (const role in updatedGroupedUsers) {
                        const userIndex = updatedGroupedUsers[role].findIndex(
                            (user) => user.id === targetUserId
                        );

                        if (userIndex !== -1) {
                            const isConversationSelected =
                                selectedConversation && selectedConversation.id === targetUserId;

                            updatedUser = {
                                ...updatedGroupedUsers[role][userIndex],
                                lastMessageTimestamp: message.createdAt,
                                unreadMessages: isConversationSelected
                                    ? 0
                                    : (updatedGroupedUsers[role][userIndex].unreadMessages || 0) + 1,
                            };

                            updatedGroupedUsers[role].splice(userIndex, 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (updatedUser) {
                        const userRole = updatedUser.roleName;

                        if (!updatedGroupedUsers[userRole]) {
                            updatedGroupedUsers[userRole] = [];
                        }

                        updatedGroupedUsers[userRole].unshift(updatedUser);
                        return reorderGroupsByMostRecent(updatedGroupedUsers);
                    }

                    return prevGroupedUsers;
                });
            });

            socket.on("messageRead", ({ conversationId }) => {
                // Handle messageRead event
            });
        }

        // Close popup on outside click
        const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
            if (popupRef.current && !popupRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
                setShowPopup(false);
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

        return () => {
            if (socket) {
                socket.off("updateSidebar");
                socket.off("messageRead");
            }
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, [authUser.id, socket, selectedConversation]);

    // Start or continue conversation with a user
    const startConversation = (user) => {
        const existingConversation = conversations.find(
            (conv) => conv.id === user.id
        );

        if (!existingConversation) {
            const newConversation = {
                id: user.id,
                fullName: user.fullName,
                roleName: user.roleName,
                lastMessageTimestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
                unreadMessages: 0,
            };

            setConversations((prev) => [...prev, newConversation]);
        }

        setSelectedConversation(user); // Set selected conversation
        setShowPopup(false); // Close popup after starting chat
    };

    const roles = Object.keys(groupedUsers);

    // Filter users based on the search term
    const filteredGroupedUsers = Object.fromEntries(
        roles.map(role => [
            role,
            groupedUsers[role].filter(user =>
                user.fullName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
            )
        ])
    );

    return (
        <div className='py-1 flex flex-col overflow-auto'>
            <button
                onClick={() => setShowPopup(true)}
                className='bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded mb-4'
            >
                Start New Chat
            </button>
            
            {showPopup && (
                <div className='popup-overlay'>
                    <div className='popup-content' ref={popupRef}>
                        <button onClick={() => setShowPopup(false)} className='close-button'>
                            &times;
                        </button>
                        <h3>Select User to Start Chat</h3>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Search users..."
                            className="border rounded p-2 mb-4 w-full"
                            value={searchTerm}
                            onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        {roles.map(role => (
                            <div key={role}>
                                <div className='font-bold divider text-base text-gray-800'>{role}</div>
                                {filteredGroupedUsers[role].map(user => (
                                    <div key={user.id} className='flex items-center justify-between'>
                                        <span>{user.fullName}</span>
                                        <button
                                            onClick={() => startConversation(user)}
                                            className='text-blue-500'
                                        >
                                            Start Chat
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}

            <SearchInput groupedUsers={groupedUsers} setGroupedUsers={setGroupedUsers} />
            {conversations.map((conversation, idx) => (
                <Conversation
                    key={conversation.id}
                    conversation={conversation}
                    lastIdx={idx === conversations.length - 1}
                    unreadMessages={conversation.unreadMessages}
                />
            ))}

            {loading ? <span className='loading loading-spinner mx-auto'></span> : null}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Conversations;


export const sendMessage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { message } = req.body;
    const { id: receiverId } = req.params;
    const senderId = req.user.id;

    let fileUrl = null;
    let originalFileName = null; // Field for original file name

    // Check if a file is uploaded (using Multer for file uploads)
    if (req.file) {
      const fileBuffer = req.file.buffer; // Get file buffer from multer
      const cloudinaryResult = await uploadOnCloudinary(fileBuffer); // Upload to Cloudinary
      if (cloudinaryResult) {
        fileUrl = cloudinaryResult; // Store Cloudinary URL
        originalFileName = req.file.originalname; // Capture the original file name from Multer
      }
    }

    // Check if a conversation exists between sender and receiver, or create a new one
    let conversation = await Conversation.findOne({
      participants: { $all: [senderId, receiverId] },
    });

    if (!conversation) {
      conversation = await Conversation.create({
        participants: [senderId, receiverId],
      });
    }

    // Create a new message (includes file if present)
    const newMessage = new Message({
      senderId,
      receiverId,
      message: message || "", // Text message
      fileUrl, // Cloudinary URL if a file is uploaded
      originalFileName, // Original file name if a file is uploaded
    });

    if (newMessage) {
      conversation.messages.push(newMessage.id);
    }

    await Promise.all([conversation.save(), newMessage.save()]);

    // SOCKET IO FUNCTIONALITY
    const receiverSocketId = getReceiverSocketId(receiverId);
    if (receiverSocketId) {
      // Send message to receiver
      io.to(receiverSocketId).emit("newMessage", newMessage);

      // Emit an event to update the sidebar for all connected clients
      io.emit("updateSidebar", {
        senderId,
        receiverId,
        message: newMessage,
      });
    }

    // Respond to sender with the new message
    res.status(201).json(newMessage);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in sendMessage controller: ", error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
};

export const getUsersForSidebar = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const currentUserId = req.user?.id;
        if (!currentUserId) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid user ID" });
        }
        
        const currentUser = await User.findOne({ id: currentUserId });
        if (!currentUser) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
        }

        const currentUserRoleId = currentUser.role_id;

        // Fetch users from the external API
        const externalApiUrl = process.env.EXTERNAL_API_URL;
        const apiResponse = await axios.get(externalApiUrl);
        
        if (!apiResponse?.data?.status) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Failed to fetch users from API" });
        }

        const allUsers = apiResponse.data.data.users || [];

        // Fetch existing conversations where the current user is a participant
        const existingConversations = await Conversation.find({
            participants: currentUserId
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'messages',
            options: { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }, // Get all messages to find initiator
            select: 'senderId receiverId createdAt isRead'
        });

        // Map to store users who initiated conversation with current user
        const conversationInitiators = new Map();

        // Process existing conversations to find initiators
        existingConversations.forEach(conversation => {
            const firstMessage = conversation.messages[conversation.messages.length - 1]; // Get the first message (oldest)
            if (firstMessage) {
                const otherParticipantId = firstMessage.senderId === currentUserId 
                    ? firstMessage.receiverId 
                    : firstMessage.senderId;
                
                const latestMessage = conversation.messages[0]; // Get the latest message
                
                // Store the other participant if they initiated the conversation
                if (firstMessage.senderId !== currentUserId) {
                    conversationInitiators.set(otherParticipantId.toString(), {
                        lastMessageTimestamp: latestMessage?.createdAt || conversation.updatedAt,
                        unreadMessages: latestMessage && 
                            latestMessage.receiverId === currentUserId && 
                            !latestMessage.isRead ? 1 : 0
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        // Filter users based on hierarchy rules and existing conversations
        const filteredUsers = allUsers
            .filter(user => {
                if (!user?.id || user.id.toString() === currentUserId.toString()) return false;

                // Include user if:
                // 1. They follow hierarchy rules (current user can initiate chat)
                // 2. OR they have initiated a conversation with current user
                return canInitiateChat(currentUserRoleId, user.role_id) || 
                       conversationInitiators.has(user.id.toString());
            })
            .map(user => {
                const conversationData = conversationInitiators.get(user.id.toString());
                const roleName = validRoles[user.role?.name] 
                    ? user.role.name 
                    : roleHierarchy[user.role_id];

                return {
                    id: user.id,
                    role_id: user.role_id,
                    fullName: user.name,
                    email: user.email,
                    profilePic: user.image_url,
                    lastMessageTimestamp: conversationData?.lastMessageTimestamp || null,
                    unreadMessages: conversationData?.unreadMessages || 0,
                    roleName: roleName,
                    wasInitiator: !!conversationData
                };
            });

        // Sort users: conversations with messages first, then alphabetically
        const sortedUsers = filteredUsers.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.lastMessageTimestamp && !b.lastMessageTimestamp) return -1;
            if (!a.lastMessageTimestamp && b.lastMessageTimestamp) return 1;
            if (a.lastMessageTimestamp && b.lastMessageTimestamp) {
                return new Date(b.lastMessageTimestamp).getTime() - 
                       new Date(a.lastMessageTimestamp).getTime();
            }
            return a.fullName.localeCompare(b.fullName);
        });

        // Group users by role
        const groupedUsers = sortedUsers.reduce((acc, user) => {
            const roleName = user.roleName || `Unknown Role (${user.role_id})`;
            if (!acc[roleName]) {
                acc[roleName] = [];
            }
            acc[roleName].push(user);
            return acc;
        }, {});

        res.status(200).json(groupedUsers);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in getUsersForSidebar controller:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
};

How can I modify the API to fetch only active conversations for the sidebar? Should I use a separate endpoint or filter conversations on the frontend?
How can I ensure that real-time updates move conversations to the sidebar for both participants after initiation?
